# Multinomial distribution in PyMC

Tags: python, numpy, bayesian, pymc, multinomial

I am a newbie to pymc. I have read the required stuff on github and was doing fine till I was stuck with this problem.
I want to make a collection of multinomial random variables which I can later sample using mcmc. But the best I can do is

```
rv = [ Multinomial("rv", count[i], p_d[i]) for i in xrange(0, len(count)) ]

for i in rv:

  print i.value
  i.random()

for i in rv:

  print i.value
```

But it is of no good since I want to be able to call `rv.value` and `rv.random()`, otherwise I won't be able to sample from it.

count is a list of non-ve integers each denoting value of n for that distribution eg. a possible count can be `[26, 39, 20, 10]`

p_d is a list of lists denting probabilities. eg, a possible p_d can be `[[0.7, 0.3], [0.5, 0.1, 0.4], [0.4, 0.6], [0.8, 0.2]]`

The for loops are of no use. They just shows that the components are multinomial random variables but I think I can't use the components with mcmc to get the posterior distribution. I need some way to use mcmc with rv.

It will be perfectly fine if someone can apprise me of some function like numpy.array() (which converts list to numpy arrays) in pymc which can convert a list to something that I want. (I am sorry I am not able to express it in scientific terms but I have tried to make myself as clear as possible)
Tell me if someone needs more information.

**EDIT 1**

I have data from several games, eg `[8, 8, 10]` . It denotes when this game was played 26 times, P1(Player 1) took A1 (Action 1) 8 times, A2 8 times, A3 10 times.

(There can be different no. of actions in different games. In this example where the outcome is `[8, 8, 10]`, there are 3 actions )

I have around 200 such data (in the form of lists / numpy arrays)

I believe Multinomial distribution best describes the data.

So I wrote a deterministic function which, given a uniformly distributed random variable `tau` generates probability distribution over these actions eg, in this case , say `[0.16, 0.28, 0.56]`

You see, I have 200 such lists ,each denoting probability distribution over actions in that game. I also have a list containing 200 integers (possibly different) each denoting number of times a game was played (which I obtain by summing over the data eg the game with data `[8, 8, 10,]` was played 26 times).

Now given the observed data (a list of 200 lists eg, `[[8, 8, 10], [0, 0, 0], ....., [12, 3]]`), I want to draw posterior probability distribution of tau (which I assumed initially to be uniform)

Comment: Why do you have two outcomes on some lists and three on others?  If the games always allow actions A1, A2, and A3, I think you should always have three values on the list.

Comment: All games are different. There are some games with 3 actions, some with 2 and some with as many as 30 actions.
All games are 2 player games (though it should not matter). Hence if I have 200 such outcome lists => There are 100 different games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you want something like this:

```
from pymc import *
p_d = [[0.7, 0.3], [0.5, 0.1, 0.4], [0.4, 0.6], [0.8, 0.2]]
count =[26, 39, 20, 10]

rv = [ Multinomial("rv"+str(i), count[i], p_d[i]) for i in xrange(0, len(count)) ]

m = MCMC(rv)

m.sample(100)

print m.trace('rv0')[:]
```

Also make sure you have pymc2.3 installed not 3.

Comment: Since rv is no more a stochastic variable, I won't be able to use logp on it. This is important to check the correctness of my model. I have calculated log probability in some other non-pymc function . If the model is correct, then the log probabilities predicted by model must be similar (if other parameters (like tau in my case) are same). Kindly do share if you have some other way to check correctness of model.

Comment: Also how is MCMC able to do its job even when logp can't be invoked on  rv. If I'm not wrong, Metro-Hastings algorithm uses logp somewhere.

Comment: I think rv gets turned into a container (http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/modelbuilding.html#containers). You should be able to get the logp for the model by m.logp. You can also calculate it yourself by looping through and getting the logp for each element in RV.

Comment: just one last query, I will need to redefine logp function because there are data elements with all entries 0 eg [0, 0, 0] and their log by default comes out to be -inf which I don't want.

Comment: The cdf (drawn after this model) is pretty much close to the grid sampling results. But I am getting the difference between log probabilities as precisely 2234.7574041 for every single datapoint, which is awfully suspicious. eg
logp of Model : -1561.93347085       Grid Search : -3796.69087496 
   
Can somebody explain the reason for this behaviour